# openshift origin ui to hide the scale ui for io.openshift.non-scalable application?

Tags: openshift-origin

From this document https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/creating_images/metadata.html, I learned that add a LABEL `io.openshift.non-scalable="true"` in `Dockerfile` will hide the scale ui element on openshift console.

But seems it does not work. Is there anything wrong ? I'm using openshift-origin 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong. Unfortunately, the documentation is incorrect. Currently, neither the web console or `oc scale` look for this label. It's being tracked by a bug here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1284104

Comment: Thanks Sam. I see the bug has no update since long time ago. Do you know is there any plan to fix it ?